# TradingView widget replacing entire HTML body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to add [TradingView widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/) into my website.
This widget must load when user `select` an option from a dropdown.

**Issue**: The widget loads, but it replaces everything in the body and thereby the dropdown disappear.

**Example**:

HTML Code:

```
<select name="fx" class="fx">
    <option value="EURUSD">EURUSD</option>
    <option value="EURJPY">EURJPY</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function changeFX(fx){
  var fxWidget = new TradingView.widget({
      "width": 500,
      "height": 400,
      "symbol": "FX:"+fx,
      "interval": "1",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "White",
      "style": "2",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "hide_top_toolbar": true,
      "save_image": false,
      "hideideas": true
    }); 
  return themeWidget;
}

$(document).on('change','.fx',function(){
   var widget = changeFX(this.value);
   // do something with widget.

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/3e9jaLku/5
(select dropdown option, and see widget loads but dropdown disappears)

Any advice how to make the dropdown doesn't disappear and still TradingView widget load?

Comment: Questions referring to jdfiddle and showing no code are not accepted on SO. You should perform a major edit.

Comment: @mkluwe: added related code to the question.

Comment: @Zeigeist have a look at the answer posted by me. Dont forget to upvote and accept if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: @Manish: thanks for detailed answer, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what i can make out from the widgets website. Whatever is happening is how it works. So for this to behave the way you want. You will have to use a iframe. in your index.html and create a separate file say chart.html and give the src of the iframe as chart.html. And on change even change the src of the frame with a query parameter and read that query parameter in your chart.html and create the chart. Below is the code for your reference.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      $(document).on('change','.fx',function(){
       //var widget = changeFX(this.value);
        document.getElementById('content').src = "chart.html?value="+this.value;
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = "block";
       });
</script>
<style>
  iframe{
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    display:none;
  }
</style> 
  </head>
  <body>
   <select name="fx" class="fx">
              <option value="EURUSD">EURUSD</option>
              <option value="EURJPY">EURJPY</option>
</select>
<iframe src="chart.html" id="content" >

</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**chart.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var fx = getParameterByName('value');
      var fxWidget = new TradingView.widget({
      "width": 500,
      "height": 400,
      "symbol": "FX:"+fx,
      "interval": "1",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "White",
      "style": "2",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "hide_top_toolbar": true,
      "save_image": false,
      "hideideas": true
    }); 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a plunker **[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/El3so2RCDWXG6aIeEKP1?p=preview)** i have created.

The link that i used for the code to get queryparameters.

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Hoe it helps :)

Comment: Nice answer. A better would be to change the tradingview chart without reloading it. Dunno if it is possible though

Answer (score 9):

It's certainly too late, but you can use the argument "container_id" to choose where to place the graph.

source : https://github.com/mmmy/css3demos/wiki/Widget-Constructor

Comment: Just to clarify. The container div's id must be the same as the widget's container_id attribute for it to work without errors.

Answer (score 4):

This work for me:

**My html code:**

```
<div class="dropdown no-arrow">
  <select id="my_stocks" class="form-control">
    <option value=" ">Select Stock</option>
    <option value="AAPL">AAPL</option>
    <option value="TSLA">TSLA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container tech_analysis">
  <div id="tradingview_3418f"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.widget(
{
"width": "100%", 
"height" : 610,
"symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
"interval": "D",
"timezone": "Etc/UTC",
"theme": "Light",
"style": "1",
"locale": "en",
"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
"enable_publishing": false,
"allow_symbol_change": true,
"container_id": "tradingview_3418f"
});
</script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
</div>
```

**My Jquery:**

```
<script>
$(document).on('change','#my_stocks',function(){
  var stock_selected = $(this).val();
  var fxWidget = new TradingView.widget({
    "width": "100%", 
    "height" : 610,
    "symbol": "NASDAQ:"+stock_selected,
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "Light",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "container_id": "tradingview_3418f"
  }); 
});
</script>
```