# TradingView javascript widget deleting the UI in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I would like to integrate a JS code to a Shiny application to load a TradingView JS widget.

The problem is when the app is loading, the selector input disappears and the TradingView widget replaces the whole UI, I do not know why.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
jsCode <- 'shinyjs.pageCol = function(para){new TradingView.widget( {"width": 640,"height": 400,"symbol": para,"interval": "D","timezone": "Etc/UTC","theme": "light", "style": "1",
                              "locale": "en", "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6","enable_publishing": false, "allow_symbol_change": true,"container_id": "tradingview_e9634"}  );}'
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(selectInput("ticker", "Ticker:",
                c('NASDAQ:AMD', 'NASDAQ:TSLA', 'NASDAQ:GE'))),
    tags$head(HTML('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>')) ,
    useShinyjs(),
    div(extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("pageCol")))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$ticker, {
      js$pageCol(input$ticker)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of making it work, as described in this other post (related only to Javascript): [TradingView widget replacing entire HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649258/tradingview-widget-replacing-entire-html-body).

1. Either give the ID attribute name you chose in your `jsCode` to the div tag:

   ```r
   div(id="tradingview_e9634", extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("pageCol")))
   ```
2. Or [use an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020558/embed-iframe-inside-shiny-app): place the following chart.html file in a www subfolder of your app folder.

   ```html
   <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
       <script>
       function getParameterByName(name, url) {
         if (!url) {
           url = window.location.href;
         }
         name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
         var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
         results = regex.exec(url);
         if (!results) return null;
         if (!results[2]) return '';
         return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
       }
     var para = getParameterByName('value');
     console.log(para);
     var fxWidget = new TradingView.widget({
       "width": 640,
       "height": 400,
       "symbol": para,
       "interval": "1",
       "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
       "theme": "light",
       "style": "1",
       "locale": "en",
       "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
       "enable_publishing": false,
       "allow_symbol_change": true,
       "container_id": "tradingview_e9634"
     }); 
     </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```

   and use this app.R (simpler than the other version, no need for shinyjs):

   ```
    library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        div(selectInput("ticker", "Ticker:",
                        c('NASDAQ:AMD', 'NASDAQ:TSLA', 'NYSE:GE'))),
        htmlOutput("frame")

      ),
      server = function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(input$ticker, {
          query <- paste0("chart.html?value=", input$ticker)

          output$frame <- renderUI({
            tags$iframe(src=query, width=660, height=450)
          })
        })
      })
   ```